# Sort xml data into an array using groovy

Tags: arrays, sorting, groovy

I'm getting some data from an XML file which gets updated very frequently, I need to get the data from the XML file and parse it into an array and sort it in a very specific way.

The XML file looks something like this.(will have lot more data then shown, jumbled but similar)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
 <groupId>groupName</groupId>
 <artifactId>artifactName</artifactId>
 <versioning>
  <versions>
   <version>abranchname001-A1</version>
   <version>abranchname001-A2</version>
   <version>abranchname001-A3.ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949</version>
   <version>abranchname001-A4</version>
   <version>abranchname001-A40</version>
   <version>abranchname001-A50.085bb3bcb608e1e8451d4b2432f8ecbe6306e7e7</version>
   <version>abranchname001-A61</version>
   <version>abranchname001-A64</version>
   <version>abranchname001-A70.a11bef06a3f659402fe7563abf99ad00de2209e6</version>
   <version>bbranchname003-A200</version>
   <version>bbranchname003-A2</version>
   <version>bbranchname003-A20</version>
   <version>bbranchname003-A22</version>
   <version>cbranchname002-Alpha-A20</version>
   <version>cbranchname002-Alpha-A200</version>
   <version>cbranchname002-Alpha-A22.f3abe64fc121b75f3f0566c73f2f1a4e8fffd68e</version>
   <version>cbranchname002-Alpha-A23</version>
  </versions>
 </versioning>
</metadata>
```

I need to create an array as below (sort by branchnames + sort by number after "-A" neglecting whats after period if period exists)

```
['abranchname001-A70.a11bef06a3f659402fe7563abf99ad00de2209e6',
'abranchname001-A64',
'abranchname001-A61',
'abranchname001-A50.085bb3bcb608e1e8451d4b2432f8ecbe6306e7e7',
'abranchname001-A40',
'abranchname001-A4',
'abranchname001-A3.ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949',
'abranchname001-A2',
'abranchname001-A1',
'bbranchname003-A200',
'bbranchname003-A22',
'bbranchname003-A20',
'bbranchname003-A2',
'cbranchname002-Alpha-A200',
'cbranchname002-Alpha-A23',
'cbranchname002-Alpha-A22.f3abe64fc121b75f3f0566c73f2f1a4e8fffd68e',
'cbranchname002-Alpha-A20']
```

This is what I have, what am I missing in this groovy script?

```
File xmlfile = new File("./data.xml")

def dataArray = new XmlSlurper().parse(xmlfile).versioning.versions.version.collect{ (it=~/\d+|\D+/).findAll() }.sort().reverse().collect{ it.join() }

assert dataArray == [""] //for testing output
//return dataArray  // actual code step
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File("data.xml"))
def p   = /([^-]+)-\D*(\d+)/

def versions = xml.versioning.versions.version.collect { v ->
  v.text() 
}.sort { a, b -> 
  def am = (a =~ p)
  def bm = (b =~ p)
  am[0][1] <=> bm[0][1] ?: (bm[0][2] as int) <=> (am[0][2] as int)
}

versions.each { v -> 
  println v
}
```

when run on your data set, prints out:

```
~> groovy solution.groovy
abranchname001-A70.a11bef06a3f659402fe7563abf99ad00de2209e6
abranchname001-A64
abranchname001-A61
abranchname001-A50.085bb3bcb608e1e8451d4b2432f8ecbe6306e7e7
abranchname001-A40
abranchname001-A4
abranchname001-A3.ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949
abranchname001-A2
abranchname001-A1
bbranchname003-A200
bbranchname003-A22
bbranchname003-A20
bbranchname003-A2
cbranchname002-Alpha-A200
cbranchname002-Alpha-A23
cbranchname002-Alpha-A22.f3abe64fc121b75f3f0566c73f2f1a4e8fffd68e
cbranchname002-Alpha-A20

~>
```

notes:

- changed the regex to match for two groups, first one the branch name, second one the number (`200`) in the postfix (`A200`)
- changed the sort to sort primarily on branch name and secondarily reverse sort on the number in the postfix
- the [two arg sort closure](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#sort(groovy.lang.Closure)) expects an int return value. The [space ship operator](http://groovy-lang.org/single-page-documentation.html#_spaceship_operator) `<=>` is perfect for this.
- the [elvis operator](http://groovy-lang.org/single-page-documentation.html#_elvis_operator) `?:` makes it so that if the branch names are equal (the expression before the `?:` returns zero) we then continue with comparing the numbers in the postfix
- should be noted that using the above, the branch names are still compared using alphabetical odering, thus if the branch names were 'A200', 'A22' and 'A20', they would be sorted as [A20, A200, A22] and not [A20, A22, A200].
- am and bm are instances of [java.util.regex.Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)
- `am[0][1]` grabs the first matching group (the first pair of parens n the regex), `am[0][2]` grabs the second matching group
- if the pattern does not match (we have an unexpected branch or postfix), this code will probably not work as expected and throw exceptions. To fix you could check for matches using `if (!am)` or similar and decide how to sort those cases by returning -1, 0, or 1.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. Just replaced `/([^-]+)-\D*(\d+)/` with strictly being ‘A’ `/([^-]+)-A(\d+)/`.